# JQuery edit <td> content

Tags: jquery

I want to replace a text inside several <td> tags. I am able to do it, but it replaces all with the first match.

The jquery code is this:

```js
var $boot = $('table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3):contains("(b)")');
$boot.html($boot.html().replace('(b)', ' <span class="b">(bootleg)</span>'));
```

```css
.b {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Comments</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>2012</td>
      <td>CD (b)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BB</td>
      <td>2013</td>
      <td>LP (b)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CC</td>
      <td>2014</td>
      <td>CD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DD</td>
      <td>2014</td>
      <td>CD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>EE</td>
      <td>2015</td>
      <td>LP (b)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>FF</td>
      <td>2017</td>
      <td>LP Box (b)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>GG</td>
      <td>2013</td>
      <td>CD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>LL</td>
      <td>2012</td>
      <td>2CD (b)</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can see it at: https://jsfiddle.net/wjqy0fe7/

The output is:

```
Title   Year    Comments
AAA 2012    CD (bootleg)
BB  2013    CD (bootleg)
CC  2014    CD
DD  2014    CD
EE  2015    CD (bootleg)
FF  2017    CD (bootleg)
GG  2013    CD
LL  2012    CD (bootleg)
```

I would expect the following:

```
Title   Year    Comments
AAA 2012    CD (bootleg)
BB  2013    LP (bootleg)
CC  2014    CD
DD  2014    CD
EE  2015    LP (bootleg)
FF  2017    LP Box (bootleg)
GG  2013    CD
LL  2012    2CD (bootleg)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over each table cell with `.each()`:

```js
$('table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3):contains("(b)")').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace('(b)', ' <span class="b">(bootleg)</span>'));
})
```

```css
.b {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Comments</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>2012</td>
      <td>CD (b)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BB</td>
      <td>2013</td>
      <td>LP (b)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CC</td>
      <td>2014</td>
      <td>CD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DD</td>
      <td>2014</td>
      <td>CD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>EE</td>
      <td>2015</td>
      <td>LP (b)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>FF</td>
      <td>2017</td>
      <td>LP Box (b)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>GG</td>
      <td>2013</td>
      <td>CD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>LL</td>
      <td>2012</td>
      <td>2CD (b)</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!! This works!

```
$('table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3):contains("(b)")').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace('(b)', ' <span class="b">(bootleg)</span>'));
})
```